# Page break in table if there is an overflow

Tags: html, css, page-break

I have an application that generates tables for reports; however during printing - the tables may get split, which causes some of the information to get cut off ( I mean it's only printing the top half of letters and then getting split to the next page ).

I've tried page-break-before ; however that causes every table to be on it's own page. page-break-inside seems to be only supported by Opera (And I'm not even sure if that's what I want).

What I'm hoping to find, is something that if the entire table cannot be fit onto a page - it is pushed to the next; or better yet - if the next row is started on the next page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript:

- Parse data inpage and reformat
- Get table height
- If table height > page allowed height = add a new table
- Each page fits into:

  div.page {
      height: 842px;
      width: 595px;
  }

The simplest way of achieving this is a print button that opens a new page, the data is there in a format that Javascript can convert it into a table.

This is the only real accurate way I know of configuring a page of data that splits in tables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; but unfortunately that's hardcoding the page size in which is a recipe for disaster. I ended up adding vertical-align:text-top to force the contents of each cell to the top of the cell in case other cells in the row had multiple lines of content - which was pushing the other data to the center of the cell, and I also just reprinted the table headers on each page if they overflowed; I think it turned out better than forcing the data onto a new page anyhow - but thank you.